# Highcharts - loading big data-set into Treemap

Tags: highcharts, treemap

I am using TreeMap of Highcharts and get from the server dataset of 20K items.

It seems like it's taken time to the treemap to load all this dataset.

Is there a way to work with lazy loading in treemaps of highcharts?

Comment: You can load only top level items on the start and then use async drilldown to fetch more-detailed levels - see Async Setup section https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/drilldown

Comment: correct me if I wrong but does the treemap has it's own logic for drill down and up? I didn't succeed to use the async drill down with the treemap.

Comment: It seems that you are correct. The answer from [Highcharts forum](https://forum.highcharts.com/highmaps-usage-f14/drilldown-async-on-treemap-t40416/) suggests to use `setData` on point click - so this might be a way to explore.